# How can I use a tensorflow data set (TDFS) as an input for a tensorflow model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, imagenet

I am currently working with the ImageNet data set, and as you may know it is extremely large.

I have preprocessed it from .tar files into tfrecord files.

I am currently loading it using:

```
train, val = tfds.load(*)
```

So I have two tfds: train and val.

I am then adjusting them using:

```
def resize_with_crop(image, label):
    i = image
    i = tf.cast(i, tf.float32)
    i = tf.image.resize_with_crop_or_pad(i, 224, 224)
    i = tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.preprocess_input(i)
    return (i, label)

# Preprocess the images
train = train.map(resize_with_crop)
val = val.map(resize_with_crop)
```

which I am following from [here](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-train-a-neural-network-classifier-on-imagenet-using-tensorflow-2-ede0ea3a35ff).

After I try to fit my model,`d = model.fit(train, validation_data=val,...)` where the first layer has shape (None, 224, 224, 3), I receive the error: `ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3`

This issue (I believe) is because the model is being given one image at a time (so it doesn't have a 4d shape. I cannot hold the dataset in memory to restructure it as (None, 224, 224, 3) as I would for a cifar-10 dataset).

My question is, now that the images are of form (224, 224, 3) how can I use them with a tensorflow model that expects a 4d shape but I cant reshape the dataset in memory?

Or is there a way to adjust the tfds shape so that it works as an input for the model?

I am not sure I fully understand tfds, which is why I am having this issue. Additionally, I am sure that the labels will cause an issue (since theyre ints), so how can I restructure the tfds labels to be one hot encoded for the model?

Comment: Batch your data: `train = train.map(resize_with_crop).batch(32)` and for val as well.

Comment: @Kaveh Perfect thanks. Also, do you have any suggestions for one hot encoding the labels?

Comment: You can use `to_categorical` from [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/to_categorical) or `OneHotEncoder` from [Scikit-Learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) or `get_dummies` from [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html), but you don't need to one-hot encode if you use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` as loss function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tfds.load` returns a `tf.data.Dataset` object. So, you can do with the returned value(s) whatever is possible with a tensorflow dataset.

The 4D data of input is mostly expected as `(batch_size, Hight, Width, Channel)`. So, if your images are in shape (224,224,3), you need to batch them in order to add batch dimension to be compatible with what model expects.

For batching a dataset, simply use `.batch(batch_size)`:

```
train = train.batch(32)
val = val.batch(32)
```